# Alfresco workflow starting form options not available

Tags: java, alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

I am using Alfresco community edition-5.1.x.
I'm creating a custom workflow by using kickstart. But my start task does not have the assign part.

How can i do assignation to group or individual ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will answer specifically to the individual part.

In your **workflow-model.xml**, you need to add in the part you want the assignee aspect. For example :

```
     <type name="namespace:myId">
        <parent>bpm:startTask</parent>
        .........
        <mandatory-aspects>
            <aspect>bpm:assignee</aspect>
        </mandatory-aspects>
    </type>
```

Then, reference it in your **share-config-custom.xml** form part :

```
<form>
   <field-visibility>
      .....
      <show id="bpm:assignee" />
      .....
   </field-visibility>
 .........
```

Finally, in your **workflow.bpmn** you could assign the next task to the chosen assignee :

He is an example with the Eclipse Activiti tool :

[image: Assignee configuration]

Or just the same thing in the xml view :

```
<userTask id="alfrescoUsertask2" name="Validation Step" activiti:assignee="${bpm_assignee.properties.userName}" activiti:formKey="namespace:myId"></userTask>
```

For the "assign to a GROUP" part, it should be something similar with the `bpm:groupAssignee` model.

Comment: I have added my bpmn20.xml file

<startEvent id="start" activiti:initiator="initiatorUserName" activiti:formKey="mentoratraining:start" activiti:candidateGroups="${bpm_groupAssignee.properties.authorityName}"></startEvent>

And i added my model file also 
<mandatory-aspects>
            <aspect>bpm:assignee</aspect>
        </mandatory-aspects>

But its not help me i am getting workflow not started error

Comment: You are mixing group and user. If you want to select group (${bpm_groupAssignee.properties.authorityName}), use the bpm:groupAssignee  aspect.

Comment: whatever your mentioned above i did it everything i am getting now :  "org.activiti.engine.ActivitiException: Unknown property used in expression: ${bpm_groupAssignee.properties.authorityName}"
please help me i am stuck

Comment: So you added in the model this part ?  <mandatory-aspects> <aspect>bpm:groupAssignee</aspect> </mandatory-aspects>

Comment: already i have some <mandatory-aspects> i added at last like this

Comment: Ah you have put in your share***.xml <show id="bpm:groupAssignee" /> instead of <show id="bpm:assignee" />. Have you tried to start from something clean ?

Comment: Yes cleared everything still am getting same error workflow not start

Comment: Ok, the activiti:candidateGroups="${bpm_groupAssignee.properties.authorityName" should be set to the next step, not the start task, because it represent the person/group the task is assigned to. This is why you have the error : when you start a workflow, the "bpm_groupAssignee" param is not set. When you chose in your form a new assignee (person/group), then the "bpm_groupAssignee" param is set, and in the next step you can set the assignee to the group/person you have chosen with the activiti:candidateGroups element.

Comment: Yes modified 3 file now able to assign groups but inside group people not get any notification their alfresco dashboard page